# Why my ExpressJS is not able to get the static directory?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, web-deployment

I saw a LOT of topics about this one but they're not working for me...

WHen I run my app on the server, I get:

Refused to apply style from 'https://kajix.com.br/static/css/2.a9768876.chunk.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

My server.js (actually is main.js in my project- but I know that most of the people knows like server.js) is like this. (Important to say that the parts that are commented are the parts that I tried before. In every attempt, I changed the url from the index.html. )

```
const path = require("path");
var http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// app.use("/static", express.static("static"));
// app.use("/static", express.static(__dirname + "/static"));
// app.use("/css", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "static/css")));
// app.use("/js", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "static/js")));
// app.use("/media", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "static/media")));
app.use(express.static("static")); 

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));
});

const port = 21168;
app.listen(port);
```

and now the HEAD tag of my index file.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon-kajix.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json" />
    <title>Kajix - Marketing Digital</title>
    <link href="/static/css/2.a9768876.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/static/css/main.f05032b6.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

Could you guys help me?

EDIT:

Here's my project directory tree

[image: My Directory]

Answer (score 0):

try these modifications in your nodejs:

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"static")));
```

and in your index.html:

```html
<head>
    <link href="/css/2.a9768876.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/css/main.f05032b6.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

remove the `/static/` path from your `bundle.js` if it contains it.
hope this helps.

Comment: Same problem but as like the previous attempts, the console just shows me the diferrent URL (as I changed in the index.html) -> Refused to apply style from 'https://kajix.com.br/css/2.a9768876.chunk.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.